# Geth Clique: can change config params in genesis and still retain the existing blocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis, hardforks, forks

I have altered my custom Geth private chain Clique PoA, but it seems after I do that I encounter:

`BAD BLOCK
Error: invalid receipt root hash`

Is it possible to:

1. change the Geth code
2. add a new hard fork block in `config.go`
3. specify the block in `genesis.json`
4. re-init the genesis file
5. retain the existing blocks and have my private chain continue as normal?

I am assuming that adding new hard fork blocks in `config.go` work the same in Clique. Is my assumption correct?

Or do I need to wipe the entire chaindata every time I change the geth code?